# Partial fetch from Azure Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-table-storage

I want to fetch rows from Azure tables in partial batches (there are lot of rows being returned) and to show them on a User Interface. The UI calls a Web Api which fetches these records from Azure tables. What is the best way to implement this functionality?

Comment: What is the partial batches means? Do you want to query the entities? Or do you have some special requirement?

Comment: @Rena-MSFT 's answer is the correct one, you should flag it as such.
Cheers.